# Install older Ruby versions on a M1 MacBook?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, apple-m1, asdf-vm

Installing Ruby 3.0.x works fine on M1 MacBooks using `rbenv` or `asdf`. But older versions like 2.7.x and 2.6.x are having various issues. How do I fix them, without installing both x86 and ARM versions of `homebrew` at the same time?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In order to make installing of Ruby versions 2.6.x or 2.7.x successful on M1 MacBook using either `rbenv` or `asdf` *(asdf is used in this example)* follow these steps:

Upgrade to the latest version of `rbenv` or `asdf-ruby` plugin using your prefered installation method. In my case it's `asdf-ruby` installed over homebrew:

```sh
brew upgrade asdf
asdf plugin update ruby
```

Reinstall the current versions of `openssl`, `readline` and `ruby-build` in order to have the latest versions and configs:

```sh
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies readline
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ruby-build
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1
brew install -s readline
brew install -s openssl
brew install -s ruby-build
```

In your shell config `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` add the following ENV variables:

```sh
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib:$LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include:$CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib:$LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include:$CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

This will ensure that the proper libraries and headers are used during the installations and it will ignore the `implicit-function-declaration` that is preventing some versions to continue installation. Note that for some other shells like `fish` the exporting of these variables will be a bit different.

Now start a new terminal session and you can try installing the older ruby versions:

```sh
asdf install ruby 2.7.2
asdf install ruby 2.6.5
```

Note that really old versions below 2.5 might still have issues. Most of the credits go to [this Github issue](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/184).

##### UPDATE

For Ruby 2.2 please change the following variable:

```sh
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=openssl@1.0
```

And do a

```sh
asdf reshim ruby
```

Thanks @xjlin0 for this update

Comment: I've a legacy project still creeping along with 2.4, and your recommendations worked in my testing. Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned it at the time as it could be helpful to others - I was using rbenv and it's ruby-build for my testing.

Comment: i confirm it works with asdf but not rbenv did same steps

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned I did try it with asdf, I just assumed it should work with rbenv since asdf is using rbenv under the hood. And for @Yoopergeek it did work with rbenv ‍♂️

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling OpenSSL using these instructions jacked up my rubygems and npm registry fuctionality, and I had to manually install CA certs.

Comment: Actually, still having issues in various places. For example: `Warning UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
`

Comment: for 2.2 https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1742#issuecomment-835790760 plus set RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS to openssl@1.0 and `asdf reshim ruby`

Comment: @xjlin0 I've updated the post with your info. Thanks!

Comment: What is `libffi`? As far as I know you need to export `/opt/homebrew/opt/readline` and `opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3`
eg.:

`export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)"`,  
`export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"`,  
`export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"`,  
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/pkgconfig"`
[code]

Comment: @MarceloXavier libffi is a C foreign function interface library. As far as I remember without this setting my installers were not passing successfully.

Comment: @orthodoX asdf *does not* use rbenv under the hood, it uses ruby-build.  Both projects are hosted by the rbenv org on Github, but they are not the same.  rbenv is a ruby version manager, the same function as asdf.  rbenv also uses ruby-build under the hood.

Comment: I have rosetta installed, so with `arm64` doesn't worked.


```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/mberrueta/.zprofile
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"

arch -x86_64 brew install asdf
asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git
asdf plugin update ruby

arch -x86_64 brew install -s readline
arch -x86_64 brew install -s openssl
arch -x86_64 brew install -s ruby-build


asdf install ruby 2.6.9
```

Comment: Please be careful suggesting this type of forced install with "ignore" flags, this is dangerous and may screw up another tool that requires this dependencies; KEEP THIS IN MIND if you use this answer!!!

Comment: This does not work on BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.6 using ruby-build 20220910.1)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on macOS 12.6

Comment: not working for me on Mac OS 12.5.1

Comment: A similar comment than the one for ruby <= 2.2.x should appear for ruby versions above 3.0.0, the recommended openssl version in that case is openssl@3

Comment: This answer should not be the recommended one: mess too much with some important libs of your system for a not guaranted result.

Answer (score 15):

This simple command helped me

```
RUBY_CFLAGS="-w" rbenv install 2.5.5
```

Comment: wow this really works as of january 23 unlike accepted version which is also much more work

Comment: This worked for me, thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Faced with an error on M2 Pro, Ventura 13.4.1

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/mkrasikov/.rvm/log/1688468004_ruby-2.7.4/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Solved with:

```
brew install rbenv
RUBY_CFLAGS="-w" rbenv install 2.7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

For OSX v12.6.1 with frum on M1 Macbook Pro 2021 I used the following exports in ~/.bash_profile after installing ruby-build with brew to successfully build ruby 2.6.5

```
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: this works for Ruby 3, too

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue for Ruby 2.2.2 and many gems were dependent on that. So I have created a docker container for ubuntu 18.04 and then installed ruby on it. It's working.

Comment: Yes, I prefer to have my development setup dockerized for all the projects as well. But I do have the languages I work with installed locally for the sake of linting and formatting used by the editors. It's doable to use lint/format from within the containers themselves but the experience is still not that great and easy to set up for a lot of editors. That's why I keep just Ruby/Elixir versions installed locally, but all other services I use strictly from Docker, like Posgres, Redis, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved for [ruby 2.7.10 and onward](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/6440). If you're using a version manager, such as [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), this should be resolved for the full 2.7.x version range (not just 2.7.10).

The underlying issue is an [incompatibility introduced in Xcode 14](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18912). One solution is to downgrade to Xcode 13, so that you can build ruby. This isn't a viable path for many users, so another option is to get an already built version of ruby for your architecture, which occurs with downloads from `homebrew`.

Homebrew has a formulae for [ruby@2.6](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ruby@2.6) that will run on MacOS M1 (arm) and older intel based models (x86). You can install this with
`brew install ruby@2.6` which will install ruby 2.6.10. If that's all you need, you can stop here.

If you want to use ruby 2.6 with a version manager such as `asdf`, you can do the following:

```
brew install ruby@2.6
ln -s $(brew --prefix ruby@2.6) ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.10
asdf reshim ruby 2.6.10
```

Answer (score -2):

thanks to @orthodox

with rosetta I has brew under arm64. so I uninstall it, and reinstall with x86 and worked

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/mberrueta/.zprofile
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"

arch -x86_64 brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies   asdf
arch -x86_64 brew install asdf
arch -x86_64 brew upgrade asdf
asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git
asdf plugin update ruby


arch -x86_64 brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force openssl
arch -x86_64 brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies  --force ruby-build
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1
arch -x86_64 brew install -s readline
arch -x86_64 brew install -s openssl
arch -x86_64 brew install -s ruby-build



export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib:$LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include:$CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib:$LDFLAGS"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include:$CPPFLAGS"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

asdf install ruby 2.6.9
```

Comment: so no solution without using brew with  x86