# SSL verification error when running `gem install bundler` on fresh MacBookPRO M1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, bundler, apple-m1

Successfully installed `asdf install ruby 2.6.6` following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012676/install-older-ruby-versions-on-a-m1-macbook) on my fresh MacBook Pro M1 2021, and trying to run `gem install bundler`, but getting this:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % gem install bundler                                                           
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
  Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
```

I tried to open Mac's `Keychain Access` window and specify `Always Trust` option for every `GlobalSign` certificate, but no luck.

`OS: MacOS Monterey 12.0.1`

`ruby -v: 2.6.6`

`gem -v: 3.0.3`

`Homebrew: 3.3.4`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I also followed that guide, and ran into this issue. Try this:
check directory `/opt/homebrew/etc`
see if you have `openssl@1.1`
if not, you probably need to reinstall using `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`. openssl1.1 is what i use for ruby 2.6.5, you might need to check that for your ruby version.

Also, i am not entirely sure about this, but I also added a couple more env variables to the ~/zshrc file following this [guide](https://medium.com/@3minus1/installing-old-ruby-versions-on-apple-m1-step-by-step-guide-501bb893c843). Be sure you are changing the "openssl@1.0" to "openssl@1.1" or whatever your ruby version uses.

Comment: I'm using `rbenv` with `2.6.3` and ran into the same issue. `brew reinstall openssl@1.1` fixed it for me.