# Ruby Install failed on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm, apple-m1, asdf

Am trying to install Ruby on MacBook M1 but it failed every time,
Command used: *rvm install ruby 2.7.2* (none of the version worked)

```
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/myName/.rvm/log/1641910054_ruby-2.7.2/install.log

There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

And after checking logs, I found

```
*** Following extensions are not compiled:
gdbm:
Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
Check ext/gdbm/mkmf.log for more details.
openssl:
    Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
    Check ext/openssl/mkmf.log for more details.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
```

I have also tried other version managers like *asdf* but no luck.

**Background**: *HomeBrew* installed successfully, paths also set, *rvm* also installed. Command line tools for Xcode also installed, using latest version of Xcode 13.2.1 and latest macOS Monterey 12.1.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012676/install-older-ruby-versions-on-a-m1-macbook helps?

Comment: I tried to install Ruby through asdf but it didn't work, may be due to some conflicts with paths. So I had to switch back to Big Sur and rvm worked fine, check below comment for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe rvm just doesnt work properly on m1 yet? Try just using `brew install ruby` for now. It should work the same.

Comment: Well after spending 3,4 days on this, I came to know that rvm works fine on M1 but rbenv doesn't. So I tried to install Ruby on new machine with rvm and copied ruby particular version folder to rbenv directory (because my project was using rbenv to install ruby).

Comment: I had to switch back to Big Sur OS to try out things from scratch, and fortunately rvm worked fine this time.