# Fix openssl@3 error when installing Ruby with RVM on macOS Monterey

Tags: openssl, rvm

Tried multiple solutions:

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew)
- [RVM](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4484) GitHub (also [participated](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4484#issuecomment-484393897) in the discussions)

Actually, fail to install another Ruby version (3.1.0 is installed without issues) on Apple M1 chip macOS Monterey.

So here are installed versions details:

```
➜  ~ which openssl
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl
➜  ~ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021)
built on: Tue Dec 14 16:16:25 2021 UTC
platform: darwin64-arm64-cc
options:  bn(64,64)
compiler: clang -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3"
ENGINESDIR: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.1/lib/engines-3"
MODULESDIR: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.1/lib/ossl-modules"
Seeding source: os-specific
CPUINFO: OPENSSL_armcap=0x7f
```

Here are the lines added to the `.zshrc` file following the `openssl` setup:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Used RVM version:

```
➜  ~ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
```

When installing a Ruby version (no matter, 3.0.0 or lower, for example, 2.6.5), it raises the error:

```
➜  ~ rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
ruby-2.6.5 - #removing src/ruby-2.6.5 - please wait
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/serguei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.5 - #downloading ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.5 - #extracting ruby-2.6.5 to /Users/serguei/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5 - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.6.5 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/serguei/.rvm/log/1647291878_ruby-2.6.5/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here is the content of the created log file:

```
+__rvm_make:0> make -j8
    BASERUBY = /Users/serguei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
    CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/-darwin21 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0 
    DLDFLAGS = -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/serguei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib -compatibility_version 2.6 -current_version 2.6.5  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = 
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
...
ast.c:132:19: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_funcall(f, rb_intern("set_encoding"), 2, rb_enc_from_encoding(enc), rb_str_new_cstr("-"));
...
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object cgi/escape.bundle
6 warnings generated.
linking shared-object psych.bundle
4 warnings generated.
linking shared-object zlib.bundle
422 warnings generated.
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

The only successfully installed version is `3.1.0`:

```
➜  ~ rvm list
=* ruby-3.1.0 [ arm64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Any idea ?

Update

There is an [issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4484#issuecomment-1696671781) describing possible fixes.
I don't use rvm any more and opted to [ASDF](https://asdf-vm.com).

Comment: It seems like this solution should work:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012676/install-older-ruby-versions-on-a-m1-macbook

Answer (score 7):

For ruby versions `2.6.x`, `2.7.x`, and maybe for `3.0.0` also. Try installing these versions with `openssl@1.1`.

First, try installing openssl@1.1 with homebrew

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then try installing ruby 2.6.5 with this openssl

```
rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1`
```

This may work.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig rvm install [ruby-version] --with-openssl-lib=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 --with-openssl-include=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1
```

Comment: Was encountering this a lot; `rvm` kept trying to use openssl@3 during `make` and this answer got me through! Thanks

Comment: (note: I am using an `arm64` machine)

Comment: ditto to Paul S, on arm64 as well

Comment: That's the only answer that works for me, others using `--with-openssl-dir` doesn't work since when I try to install a gem it gives me a OpenSSL error. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

try

```bash
rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rvm install 2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl` ?
Last time it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install conflicting gem with required openssl version.

I faced similar issue, json-jwt lib was looking for openssl@3. Instead of reinstalling entire ruby, just reinstalled json-jwt gem.

```
gem install json-jwt -v 1.15.3 -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on an M1 MacBook Pro running Sonoma:
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig" rvm install 2.5.5 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)`

I am not sure why `--with-openssl-dir` isn't sufficient, seems like a bug with RVM