# Ruby 3.1.2 build with rvm failed during compile on macOS Monterey 12.4

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Attempting to install Ruby 3.1.2 with `rvm install ruby-3.1.2`, but receiving an error after RVM begins compiling. I need to install this specific version for an employer and cannot upgrade to 3.1.4.

The error message reads:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/Blue/.rvm/log/1696038460_ruby-3.1.2/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The log in question seems to run smoothly until this point:

```
compiling objspace_dump.c
openssl_missing.c:24:13: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct X509_crl_st'
        *psig = crl->signature;
                ~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/include/openssl/types.h:162:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct X509_crl_st'
typedef struct X509_crl_st X509_CRL;
               ^
openssl_missing.c:26:13: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct X509_crl_st'
        *palg = crl->sig_alg;
                ~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/include/openssl/types.h:162:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct X509_crl_st'
typedef struct X509_crl_st X509_CRL;
               ^
openssl_missing.c:36:13: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct X509_req_st'
        *psig = req->signature;
                ~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/include/openssl/x509.h:283:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct X509_req_st'
typedef struct X509_req_st X509_REQ;
               ^
openssl_missing.c:38:13: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct X509_req_st'
        *palg = req->sig_alg;
                ~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.2/include/openssl/x509.h:283:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct X509_req_st'
typedef struct X509_req_st X509_REQ;
               ^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [openssl_missing.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
```

The testing code to ensure that RVM is successfully installed listed on the website, `type rvm | head -n 1`, runs successfully. Installing with OpenSSL 1.1 as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474290/fix-openssl3-error-when-installing-ruby-with-rvm-on-macos-monterey) results in the same error.

I'm on a MacBook Air 2022 with M2 chip. OpenSSL is on version 3.1.2 (Aug 2023). Make is version 3.8.1. RVM is latest. No binary rubies are available for this version of OSX on rvm.io. What other steps might I take to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does _any_ Ruby version compile with RVM? Does the latest Ruby compile? I.e. step 1 is to figure out of this is a Ruby version-specific problem, or if it's a general compilation (most likely OpenSSL) issue on your computer.